# play 2: "reference to form is ambiguous" error message in template

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to build a play2 application following code examples from a book:
I am stumbling on creating a form template with the following definition:
    @(productForm: Form[Product])

```
@main("Product Form") {
<h1>Product Form</h1>
@helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()) {
    <fieldset>
    <legend> Product (@productForm("name").valueOr("new"))</legend>
    @helper.inputText(productForm("wan"), '_label -> "EAN")
    @helper.inputText(productForm("name"), 'label -> "Name")
    @helper.textarea(productForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")
    </fieldset>
    <input type"submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    <a a class=btn" href="@routes.Products.list()"> Cancel </a>
    }
 }
```

I get the following eclipse (I have the scala ide plugin installed)

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - reference to Form is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import play.data._ and 
 import play.api.data._
```

Should I ignore the message ? `play compile` runs fine, but I don't get any output from the form.

Comment: What version of Play are you using? Which line is the message coming from?

Comment: I use play 2.2.1. After a bit of deep bug hunting, the form now works, but the error message goes on. So I guess the code is right but Eclipse is wrong !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To correct the eclipse error I had to insert

```
 @(productForm: play.data.Form[Product])
```

instead of:

```
 @(productForm: Form[Product])
```

Comment: But when compiling in play this is not an issue. Why should the code be more verbose to satisfy eclipse?